# Excel: remove part of cell's string value

Tags: excel, google-sheets, cell

I'm working in Google Spreadsheet, (which I can easily download into an Excel file) and I want to remove the word and colon (which is Email: in every case) that precedes each cell. For example, removing Email: from Email: ted@gmail.com to be just ted@gmail.com  How do I best do this, as I using the Find and Replace function, and not getting it right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing find and replace should work (assuming the text you want to remove is always email:) so not sure what is happening there. Just replace it with nothing

An alternative is: 
Go to data menu > split text into columns

Then select : as a custom separator. It should put the email in the next column along and leave the word 'email' in the original column with the colon gone.

Comment: ... or ignore the first column altogether.

Comment: Absolutely perfect.  And thanks for responding so quickly!

Answer (score 0):

In Excel the Replace shortcut is [ctrl]+H.

[image]

Comment: What app did you use to make that GIF?

Answer (score 0):

Just put this code in the next column in the Google sheet to clean it if you don't want to export out to Excel. But this applies for Excel as well.

```
=RIGHT(A2,LEN(A2)-FIND(" ",A2))
```

Since the `Email:` is fixed, the code can also be

```
=RIGHT(A2,LEN(A2)-7)
```

A screenshot of what it looks like

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the response!